# Docusign Post Recipient View

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the **DocuSign API**, however I'm receiving this error when using the "Post Recipient View" API call:

```
UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT: "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope"
```

I'm passing the API the following parameters: returnUrl, authenticationMethod, userName and email.

The envelope was created using the DocuSign website, so I don't have the **clientUserId**. Is this an issue?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `clientUserId` when requesting the signing URL for a given recipient.  When you create an envelope through the DocuSign Web Console I believe the recipient is designated as a remote recipient by default (ie they are designated as one who will receive email notifications to begin signing).

Since they are a remote signer I believe the `clientUserId` will not be present, however you can easily check this.  Make the [Get Recipient Status](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Recipient%20Status.htm) API call and if they have a `clientUserId` present and it's value set then try that combo when requesting signing URL.

Otherwise, try creating a new envelope (through the API) and make sure you set a unique `clientUserId` for any recipient that will be an embedded signer, then make sure to use that same combo of data when requesting the signing URL and it should work.

Comment: **Get Recipient Status** did not include a `clientUserId` field for the documents I created through the Web Console. 

Can you confirm that documents created within the _DocuSign Web Console_ cannot be retrieved with **Post Recipient View** API call?

Comment: Confirmed that this is the intended behavior.  When creating through Web Console you can only designate remote recipients (with the one exception being In Person Signing recipient type - ie someone physically next to you that will be signing).  Only API created recipients can set the `clientUserId` to make the recipient embedded so they can sign through a 3rd party app.